# char type cause loop explosion

Tags: c++, while-loop, infinite-loop

I was wondering if anyone could tell me why the following code;

```
int main ()
{

        while((true))
        {
            int userChoice;
            //fprintf(stdout, "Press 1 for Coke.\nPress 2 for Sprite.\nPress 3 for Dr. Pepper.\nPress 4 for Mountain Dew.\nPress 5 for Monster.\nPress 6 for Help.\n\n");

            fprintf(stdout, "What would you like? (Press 6 for assistance): ");
            std::cin >> userChoice;
            if ((userChoice == 1))
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "\nYou get a Coke and you get a Coke, EVERYONE GETS A COKE!\n\n");
            }
            else if ((userChoice == 2))
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "\nDispensing Sprite.\n\n");
            }
            else if ((userChoice == 3))
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "\nDropping the Dr. P!\n\n");
            }
            else if ((userChoice == 4))
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "\nDo the Dew!\n\n");
            }
            else if ((userChoice == 5))
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "\nHere's your Monster, but don't go crazy\n\n");
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "\nPress 1 for Coke.\nPress 2 for Sprite.\nPress 3 for Dr. Pepper.\nPress 4 for Mountain Dew.\nPress 5 for Monster.\nPress 6 for Help.\n\n");
            }
        }

}
```

causes an infinite loop instead of printing the "else" statement when a non-integer is recieved via std::cin.

I'm assuming it is because userChoice is stored as an integer.  How would I prevent this from happening?  First guess would be to change it to a string or char but would like a better explanation...

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: From Comments;

Thank you for the answer and input;

- The if's instead of switch statements are part of the "Learning". Im brand new, the "beginners challenge" wanted it in if's, then change it to use a switch.
- the parentheses, Code::Blocks was throwing compiler warnings so i added them...
- using the different printf/scanf etc makes sense.

Maybe more specifically i should ask; why is it that when i input a "6", it properly breaks and returns to the top of the loop but when i input an "a" it repeatedly prints out the else statement as fast as possible

Comment: Why won't it be infinite?  `while(true)` makes it infinite.

Comment: @BatCoder please read the code careful. It's `while((true))` This is Super infinite.

Comment: `fprintf(stdout, "What would you like? (Press 6 for assistance): "); std::cin >> userChoice;` is one of the most strange code I've ever seen.

Comment: in the else statement you should `clear` and `getline` to clean `std::cin` for further input - better yet, you should accept input using `getline` and then parse that input, this also eats multiple space-separated inputs, allows outputting of parser error messages and would leave `std::cin` in working order automatically

Comment: @SergeyA, Sorry kind of figuring it out as i go...

Comment: @BeyelerStudios, Thank you for the info :).

Comment: You should pair `std::cout` with `std::cin` and `fprintf` with `scanf`.  Don't cross the streams.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews , assuming fscanf?, but what is the reasoning behind not crossing them (other than the not crossing streams joke) :P.

Comment: Synchronization between input and output.  Also, console attributes - there may be differences in the console attributes between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: if you did proper error checking, you'd already know the answer. (or, at least, be closer than you currently are)

Long answer since `userChoice` is of type `int`: `std::cin >> userChoice;` ***fails*** when it tries to parse `a`. It does nothing to the value of `userChoice` and sets the fail bit on `std::cin`.

Since `userChoice` retains the previous value, it simply repeats whatever the previous choice does.

Furthermore, next time you execute `std::cin >> userChoice;`, you're doing it on a stream that's still in the fail state, and so the operation does nothing yet again.

To fix: test for errors. And if your error handling decides to continue looping, make sure to clear the flags to put `std::cin` back in the good state.

Comment: I lament the fact that so many introductions to C and C++ I/O first teach people to do I/O without error checks. :(

Comment: Would have a resource for "learning error checking", All i was aware of where compiler errors/warnings...

Marking as answer for "Long answer since userChoice is of type int: std::cin >> userChoice; fails when it tries to parse a. It does nothing to the value of userChoice and sets the fail bit on std::cin.

Since userChoice retains the previous value, it simply repeats whatever the previous choice does."

Thank you.

Comment: One solution: initialization `int userChoice = 0`

Answer (score 4):

1. When you work with `*printf` it is better to combine with `scanf( "%d", &userChoice )` instead of `cin`;
2. Use `printf( <format>, <arg )` instead of `fprintf( stdout, ...` - it is the same;
3. There are many unnecessary parentheses: `while ((true))`, `if ((userChoice == x))`;
4. For more readable syntax use `switch - case` instead of all these `if`-s;
5. The infinite loop seems as expected with `while ( true )` and without `break` nor `return`.

Comment: Why did you put actual answer as the last bullet point? I mean, your bullet points are OK, but I'd rather put the answer first.

Comment: @SergeyA 1-4 are as introduction :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and input;
- The if's instead of switch statements are part of the "Learning".  Im brand new, the "beginners challenge" wanted it in if's, then change it to use a switch.
- the parentheses, Code::Blocks was throwing compiler warnings so i added them...
- using the different printf/scanf etc makes sense.

Maybe more specifically i should ask;

why is it that when i input a "6", it properly breaks and returns to the top of the loop but when i input an "a" it repeatedly prints out the else statement as fast as possible

Comment: As suggested, do not mix printf/cin. This makes the std library try to sync C I/O and C++ I(O, which can harm performance.I suggest using only cin/cout to get type safety. Sprintf and friends is another matter, those are OK. (snprintf is better than sprintf though)

Comment: @Erik: While I agree, the library will sync them whether you use `printf` or not. (however, you can fix this with `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);`

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution for your simple program:

```
std::cin >> userChoice;  // insert the following lines
if (std::cin.fail())
{
  std::cin.clear(std::ios::goodbit);
  char c;
  std::cin >>c;
}
```